# ActiveDirectory users is not accesing UCM contents in WC portal application

Tags: active-directory, portal, webcenter, oracle-ucm

Solution: **I add security groups into UCM and works!**

I have a Webcenter tools (UCM, Portal) version 11.1.6

When i using ActiveDirectory(AD) with UCM and Portal, the group's is not converted to UCM roles.

I was configure Weblogic+AD+Uenter code hereCM using this reference: http://poornimabalagopal.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/integrating-microsofts-active-directory.html 
without configuring credential maps because it's not necessary in version 11g according documentation. My server weblogic is a cluster.

If I logon in weblogic, i can see the AD groups for an AD user.

If I logon in UCM console with this AD user, i can see the contents normally.

If I logon in webcenter portal application with this user the content was not showed. I using the content presenter for this.

The generated UCM server logs was showed below:

```
An error has occurred. The stack trace below shows more information.
!csUserEventMessage,mg96030,CIS!$!csUnableToGetRevInfo2,DEV006815!csUserInsufficientAccess3,mg96030
intradoc.common.ServiceException: !csUnableToGetRevInfo2,DEV006815!csUserInsufficientAccess3,mg96030
*ScriptStack DOC_INFO_BY_NAME
3:vcrGetDocInfoByName,dDocName=DEV0068153:checkSecurity,dID=12442,dDocName=DEV006815
at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.buildServiceException(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:2115)
at intradoc.server.Service.buildServiceException(Service.java:2326)
at intradoc.server.Service.createServiceExceptionEx(Service.java:2320)
at intradoc.server.ServiceSecurityImplementor.validateSecurityPrivilegeLevel(ServiceSecurityImplementor.java:819)
at intradoc.server.DocumentAccessSecurity.checkSecurity(DocumentAccessSecurity.java:192)
at intradoc.server.DocumentAccessSecurity.checkSecurity(DocumentAccessSecurity.java:138)
at intradoc.server.ServiceSecurityImplementor.checkSecurity(ServiceSecurityImplementor.java:373)
at intradoc.server.Service.checkSecurity(Service.java:2904)
at intradoc.server.Service.checkSecurity(Service.java:2882)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor345.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at intradoc.common.IdcMethodHolder.invokeMethod(IdcMethodHolder.java:86)
at intradoc.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethodEx(ClassHelperUtils.java:310)
at intradoc.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethod(ClassHelperUtils.java:295)
at intradoc.server.Service.doCodeEx(Service.java:620)
at webdavcomponent.WebdavHandler.checkSecurity(WebdavHandler.java:686)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor344.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at intradoc.common.IdcMethodHolder.invokeMethod(IdcMethodHolder.java:86)
at intradoc.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethodReportStatus(ClassHelperUtils.java:324)
at intradoc.server.ServiceHandler.executeAction(ServiceHandler.java:79)
at intradoc.server.Service.doCodeEx(Service.java:603)
at collections.CollectionUserHandler.checkSecurity(CollectionUserHandler.java:1429)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor343.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at intradoc.common.IdcMethodHolder.invokeMethod(IdcMethodHolder.java:86)
at intradoc.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethodReportStatus(ClassHelperUtils.java:324)
at intradoc.server.ServiceHandler.executeAction(ServiceHandler.java:79)
at intradoc.server.Service.doCodeEx(Service.java:603)
at intradoc.server.Service.doCode(Service.java:575)
at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doAction(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1643)
at intradoc.server.Service.doAction(Service.java:547)
at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doActions(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1458)
at intradoc.server.Service.doActions(Service.java:542)
at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.executeActions(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1391)
at intradoc.server.Service.executeActions(Service.java:528)
at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.executeServiceDirect(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1136)
at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.executeServiceSimple(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1076)
at intradoc.server.Service.executeServiceSimple(Service.java:4007)
at intradoc.server.vcr.VcrServiceHandler.vcrGetDocInfoByName(VcrServiceHandler.java:592)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at intradoc.common.IdcMethodHolder.invokeMethod(IdcMethodHolder.java:86)
at intradoc.common.ClassHelperUtils.executeMethodReportStatus(ClassHelperUtils.java:324)
at intradoc.server.ServiceHandler.executeAction(ServiceHandler.java:79)
at intradoc.server.Service.doCodeEx(Service.java:603)
at intradoc.server.Service.doCode(Service.java:575)
at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doAction(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1643)
at intradoc.server.Service.doAction(Service.java:547)
at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doActions(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1458)
at intradoc.server.Service.doActions(Service.java:542)
at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.executeActions(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1391)
at intradoc.server.Service.executeActions(Service.java:528)
at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doRequest(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:737)
at intradoc.server.Service.doRequest(Service.java:1956)
at intradoc.server.ServiceManager.processCommand(ServiceManager.java:437)
at intradoc.server.IdcServerThread.processRequest(IdcServerThread.java:265)
at intradoc.server.IdcServerThread.run(IdcServerThread.java:160)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

I can't find any configuration error. I'm lost!

Comment: Try uploading your configuration settings for AD.
On a cursory glance it looks like a user permission problem in your config.

Comment: In addition to configuring AD for WebLogic, have you edited the `user_projects/domains/<domain>/config/fmwconfig/jps-config.xml` and restart the Spaces managed servers?

Comment: i add security groups into UCM and works!